# Binding vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, correlation

Suppose we have a (5 x 1) vector of correlation values, and a (50 x 1) vector of random(0,1) numbers.

I am trying to create a (50 x 5) matrix, where each column is the value of the random vector multiplied by the value in the (5 x 1) correlation vector.

So for example, the third column of the matrix should be the random vector multiplied by the third value of the correlation vector. I feel this is a very basic step, but I am new to programming. The program I am using for this is R.

Comment: `outer(y, x, "*")` where y is 50x1 vector, x is 5x1 vector

Comment: just what I needed, thanks

Comment: @Khashaa, please add your comment as an answer such that this question could be closed.